# AndroidAnnotations Singleton Scope

Tags: android, singleton, android-annotations

I recently tried out AndroidAnnotations in Android. It has many interesting options and I like the way it reduces the boilerplate code.

However recently I came across the singleton scope for custom classes. I noticed that AndroidAnnotations does not restrict me from creating a new instance. For example CustomClassA obj = new CustomClassA();, even if the scope of CustomClassA is singleton.

As far as I know this should be restricted as per singleton pattern. I would like to have a solution to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AndroidAnnotations never change original code.

So it's up to the developer to make the constructor protected (or friendly) on the original class. It can't be private because generated class extends of the original one (so it has to be visible for this one).
And the constructor is private on the generated class :)

Comment: So do you think it will be better to use our own singleton implementation than using the singleton scope option provided by the Android Annotations ? As I don't want others to create new instances of that class by mistake.

Comment: If you really want to prevent direct instantiation of your bean, you can : 1. make the constructor protected and move the class in a sub-package, 2. define strict developer guidelines with your team, or 3. not using EBean annotation (but you'll have to make injection by yourself and all annotations won't be available in this class). On all my projects, we defined some guidelines and everybody's stick on it. We never had a problem because of this.